# White line below tables on click border in Outlook e-mail

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I'm working on an e-mail building tool and on e-mails received on Outlook, when I click the left border of the e-mail a white line appears below the clicked table.

[image: Behaviour]

The code is structured in this way:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed; margin: 0px auto;">
  <tbody>
    <!-- For each image: -->
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 0px; background-color: transparent;" valign="top" align="center">
        <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed; margin: auto;" align="center">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- Other nested tables that are irrelevant since their -->
              <!-- width is <= 600 and they have the same attributes -->
                <td style="border: 0px;">
                  <a><img align="center" border="0" style="display: block; margin: 0px auto; height: auto; max-width: 560px; border: 0px !important; outline: none !important; text-decoration: none !important;" src="..." height="124" width="560"></a>
                </td>
              <!-- End nested tables -->
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- repeat code above for other images -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I prevent that white line from showing up?

Comment: That's a VERY small thing to worry about! But you could try removing the !important --- Outlook will delete that style.

Comment: @Nathan I agree that it is a very small detail. Unfortunately, it was an actual complaint (although the reporter didn't know it happened only when he clicked the left border). But since in other e-mail building tools (MailChimp's for example) that doesn't happen I thought I'd try to fix it. Thanks for the "!important" tip! It did not fix the issue though.

Comment: Outlook users might make up perhaps 2% of your audience, and a further 0.1% of that 2% might click on an image (most would just scroll down). 1% of that group might be bothered for half a second that a white line appears. (It's probably a feature of Outlook.) That's why I say this is a small thing. Keep in mind we can't control everything about email, because it's not an app or website, this is code that we are inserting into another company's email program. I would guess that this is not possible to fix.